# Does credit card cash back count taxes?

Tags: credit-card, sales-tax, reward-program

If I have a 1% cash back card and spend $100 plus $6 sales tax, do I get $1 cash back or $1.06 cash back?

Comment: If that 1% card isn't just for the sake of example, you should go get a better one - 1% is a terrible rate in today's market.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica It's an example, but thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, you will get cash back for the entire amount (so $1.06 in your case).

The credit card issuer *usually* doesn't event know the tax amount, since it is charged as a single transaction.

Comment: I’d add, it also includes tips, if that’s charged in the total.

Comment: I vaguely remember something about certain things being represented separately, even if it is a single charge. However, from the CC issuer's perspective, they don't care what each part is, because the 2.5% (or whatever) they collect applies to *every* part of the charge, and that's where your cash back comes from.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica That reminds me of a "discussion" I had with a friend who was a very good tipper (at least 25%) as a way to get more "miles". He refused to believe that he was actually paying more overall.

Comment: D - You can't fix "stupid". There are many variations on this, including those who have a mortgage "for the deduction", or those who brag about getting a $3000 tax refund, when they owe, you guessed it, about $3000 on their cards while paying the minimum balance. Once the math is disrespected, I'm inclined to walk away.

Comment: To expand: the card issuer might get data indicating the amount of tax charged on the transaction if the merchant sends [Level 2 or Level 3 data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Card_Transaction_Data) when completing the charge.  As a consumer, there's pretty much no way to know whether that is happening or if your card issuer does anything with the data — you'll never have access to it.  It's irrelevant though, since cash back is (almost) always calculated based on the total purchase amount.